# LED Applications

Tags: led, failure

A 20mA, GaN, blue LED, 5mm (forward Voltage 4 volts max, reverse voltage 5 volts) in series with 47K 2W resistor worked fine as a continuity checker using power from a standard 120V AC electrical outlet.  (No reverse polarity diode in parallel was used, that was going to be the next step). After several months of general testing and usage the LED would not light. When that same LED was tested on a pair of 1.5V AA Duracells in series (3V) the LED glowed as bright as in the AC circuit. How is this possible? If reverse current/voltage breakdown was happening shouldn't LED have failed completely? I want to have 4 of these led in series, run from AC. 
Would 47K 2W resistor be acceptable and is the reverse polarity diode actually required in this case? (Setting up 2 of the 4 LEDs in the reverse polarity?)

[image: Schematic]

Comment: "shouldn't LED have failed completely?"  - Didn't it?  You said the LED does not light now, right?  LEDs don't have a very high tolerance for reverse bias, so I'm surprised it ran as long as it did.  You should include a reverse polarity protection diode.  Regarding the 3V test, was that with the 47k resistor also?

Comment: The LED works fine with the duracells (no resistor) thus not a complete failure. That is what I find perplexing.

Comment: I tried three or four cycles back and forth. In the circuit -nothing-then on the duracells, bright as new.

Comment: Maybe it got mad at you ...

Comment: I was planning on using a 1N914 general purpose diode (100v 200mA) but would be possible to avoid that by setting up a circuit with two of the diodes in reverse polarity?

Comment: So the same LED that stopped working with the 47k resistor, works from 3V with no resistor?  Is your resistor still good?

Comment: I don't follow, you want to avoid using one diode by using two?  Oh, you mean two LEDs?  Can you draw what you mean?

Comment: You need like a 1N4003 or 1N4004. Putting it with 4 in LEDs in series should be fine. 47K might be a bit high though, that's only <4mA peak current. But making it smaller you will need a bigger wattage, or use two in series.

Comment: You do not want to go back to back. They are really not meant to be reverse biased that way.

Comment: My initial thoughts exactly.  I had a duplicate (unused) resistor from a two-pack I had bought. I swapped it into the circuit and nothing again. Didn't have the multimeter with me to test the resistor, but I can assume this is still the LED Problem but what exactly could be happening.

Comment: I have seen example circuits that have the LED running in reverse polarity hence protecting each other but not back to back though.

Comment: So then the resistor + 4 LEDs on one strand and on the parallel strand a 1N4003(4) (reverse polarity). The LED brightness (almost too bright) is great with the 47K, with 4 LEDs would it change the brightness significantly? I already have the 47 K, 2W in hand. I am ready to order the other items.

Comment: Would the 1N4003(4) be good for just one of the above LEDs needed in another part of the circuit (still on 120V AC) or is there a more appropriate one for a single LED?

Comment: put the 4 LEDs 2S2P back to back so +/- 6V drop  with anything 47k to 100k.  Since the AC drop on the R is so great , adding a few LEDs makes little difference to the current, hence constant brightness.  This way it self protected.

Comment: Well LEDs I believe do wear. Since you said you were using it for a couple of months, perhaps it wore some of its intensity not enough to light in the AC circuit but enough for a battery.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: [diagram](http://imgur.com/m2WP5ir) is this the appropriate diagram?

Comment: @Trevor: Yes, any abused LED has the right to be mad at it's owner. It definitely lost ability to operate at a lower current (2.6 mA). Does this diagram represent what you were talking about? Any recommended changes to the resistor or diode?[4 LED Diagram](http://imgur.com/ZfHrQJe)

Comment: @Trevor: What what would be the appropriate diode for this case? See diagram:[single LED](http://imgur.com/RfJFKdD)

Comment: @Bradman175: That seems very likely. Using the 47k resistor I=V/R says I =120V/47K= 2.6 mA, low current for this LED, but this was still very bright. After a few months of reverse voltage abuse it probably needed more current to create visible light. The DC from the two 1.5 V Duracells provided WHATEVER current it needed to operate so it still worked. As it was slowly failing it was slowly requiring more and more current to create visible light as the junction was slowly being damaged.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: Where are you getting the +/- 6V drop?

Comment: 4 blues LEDs 2S2P back to back has a Vf=+/-6Vdc but current is regulated by the Vac/R value  120Vrms/47k=2.5mA so 6V makes little difference

Comment: as in http://imgur.com/m2WP5ir

Comment: Still needs to be a 200V+ diode, I'd go with the good old 1N4004.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, Same answer as mine, though one could argue "back to back" is the wrong term. They are actually in reverse parallel. Back to back would mean series like this ----|<--->|-----

Comment: good point ... or is that "front to front", neither of which would ever work, so we also used this phrase to imply "parallel reversed" , which does work either way :) and it was generally understood. But going forward I should be more explicit to avoid ambiguity, although yours is different with middle bridge, which also does not matter.

Comment: BTW I still like the good old single ended neon screwdrivers for this purpose. https://www.amazon.ca/SODIAL-100-500V-Voltage-Detector-Screwdriver/dp/B00SUVRL8K/ref=sr_1_3?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1491060134&sr=1-3&keywords=voltage+tester+screwdriver

Comment: Yes Neon also detects DC polarity, as would 2 LED reverse //  @JoeVokt  You were lucky to have a very low leakage LED last this long.  Reverse damage raises the activation current threshold until it stops working. It also raises junction capacitance for the advanced test eng. using VI AC mode at high f as an early indicator for ESD wounds.  I buy all my LEDs with built-in zeners in last 10 yrs and still have dozens of 200/bag.  I recall putting GaAs Red LED +R in screw hole of front door bell switch (24Vac) in 1975 and it got dim in a few years from excess -Vr.  ... switch bypassed LED+R

Comment: What arrangement of capacitative circuitry would have to be inserted after the resistor to get the 4 LEDs to gradually pulse on and off in a two second interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Trevor:

An alternative answer you hinted at but reformulated here:

In the four LED rectifier you posted, when current is coming in the positive phase (top down) current will flow trough D3 and D4. It is not possible for current to flow through the bridge because D2 is in reverse polarity. Similarly, when current is flowing in reverse phase (bottom up) current will flow through D2 then D1, but current cannot flow through the bridge because D3 is in reverse polarity. The bridge is essentially a "dead zone" so it is justified to remove it in this particular case. See diagram.

[image: Rectif-nobridge]

Here is a live link that is editable. 
 [Rectif-nobridge-live](http://www.digikey.com/schemeit/project/4-led-diagram-5M9E620201HG/)

Comment: @Trevor: I noticed you were using CircuitLab. I am curious if you have used Schemit. It is unlimited no-fee usage with a no connection limit. Free customer support. If you look at my live version it even stores the vendor number can give me a bill of materials spreadsheet for tallying costs.

Comment: @Trevor:I was interested in any comparison between CircuitLab and Schemit you could provide. Also, if you can comment on choice of circuit components that would be a plus. (visible in the Schemit link in the answer.) You might have been contacted by Mike of CircuitLab, he is now trying to write an electronic simulation textbook using CircuitLab technology.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use four LEDs. why not make it a bridge.

The following would be my alternative implementations. I'd put the LEDS in reverse parallel as indicated. That way they each turn on half cycle, and protect the other while they do.

Note the bridge is basically two stages of the TWO LED version. It is debateable whether the H-Bar is needed. However, do not be tempted to put the resistor there.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff30Bt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>